# (Java) HTTP GET request keeps getting 400 response code despite the link working perfectly fine in browser

Tags: java, rest, http, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get a JSON response from Google Trends using HTTP. This is my code snippet:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String address = "https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore?hl=en-US&tz=240&req={\"comparisonItem\":[{\"keyword\":\"Miley\",\"geo\":\"US\",\"time\":\"2012-01-01 2014-01-01\"},{\"keyword\":\"Hannah Montana\",\"geo\":\"US\",\"time\":\"2012-01-01 2014-01-01\"}],\"category\":0,\"property\":\"\"}";

    URL url = new URL(address);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("URL is "+address);

    System.out.println("Response code is " + responseCode); }
}
```

This is the output:

```
URL is https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore?hl=en-US&tz=240&req={"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"Miley","geo":"US","time":"2012-01-01 2014-01-01"},{"keyword":"Hannah Montana","geo":"US","time":"2012-01-01 2014-01-01"}],"category":0,"property":""}

Response code is 400
```

If I type the URL directly in my browser, Google gives me a JSON file with no problem. However, if I try to access that URL using Java, I am given a bad request. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try not to back slash escape the double quotes in the url string? Try using single quotes and see what happens?

Comment: @DanielH.J. I just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're saying that when you're pasting the URL that your code outputs into the browser it opens?

Comment: @fuzzyblankey Yup exactly

Answer (score 3):

You need to URL Encode the query string portion of your URL. Check out [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) for some ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem. I higly recomend [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

```
private static final HttpRequest<String> REQUEST =
        HttpRequestBuilder.createGet("https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore", String.class)
                .addDefaultRequestParameter("hl", "en-US")
                .addDefaultRequestParameter("tz", "240")
                .responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer())
                .build();

public void send() {
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = REQUEST.execute("req", "{\"comparisonItem\":[{\"keyword\":\"Miley\",\"geo\":\"US\",\"time\":\"2012-01-01 2014-01-01\"},{\"keyword\":\"Hannah Montana\",\"geo\":\"US\",\"time\":\"2012-01-01 2014-01-01\"}],\"category\":0,\"property\":\"\"}");
    System.out.println(responseHandler.getStatusCode());
    responseHandler.ifHasContent(System.out::println);
}
```

The code prints the response code 200 and response body which you get by browser.